# What is the best format to send a JavaScript Date to PHP Backend?

Tags: javascript, php, date, datetime

I want to send design an API and send a Javascript Date() Object (including Time ) to a PHP Backend.
I have a solution with timestamp now:

```
//Javascript
new Date().getTime()
```

which return a number like: 1525094344392

and I send to my PHP Backend which converts it to a PHP Datetime Object:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();

$date->setTimestamp(1525094344392 / 1000);
```

This works, but there is no timezone set, so I am wondering if there is a better solution. I have not found a simple format in Javascript which both, PHP and Javascript, easily understand.

Please provide a code sample.

Comment: Coordinated _Universal_ Time (UTC)

Comment: What do you mean by `easily understand`? So far the timestamp is the easiest way to get a date between languages. However you seem to want additional information as timezone. So...before continuing - do you need any other information than the date and timezone?  I would suggest making a JSON object with these 2 properties...should work between languages just fine!

Answer (score -1):

If you are sending this data across the world so that people can view it in different countries, if the code turns it back into date format, it will also set it to their browsers location....https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp talks about this.

> When setting a date, without specifying the time zone, JavaScript will
>   use the browser's time zone.
>
> When getting a date, without specifying the time zone, the result is
>   converted to the browser's time zone.
>
> In other words: If a date/time is created in GMT (Greenwich Mean
>   Time), the date/time will be converted to CDT (Central US Daylight
>   Time) if a user browses from central US.

Comment: Re "*…it will also set it to their browsers location*" is not correct. ECMAScript Date objects are always UTC, the host timezone offset is used only to create a UTC time value from input values, or to display date and time according to the host offset based on the internal UTC time value. The Date object itself doesn't have any offset information, it's just UTC. Please don't reference w3schools, the site is full of errors and misleading statements, nearly everything you've quoted is wrong.